# HTML5 drawImage()

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

In HTML5 canvas the function `drawImage()` can take a `Image`, be it a

> Argument `image` can be of type `HTMLImageElement`, `HTMLCanvasElement` or `HTMLVideoElement`.

A canvas returns a `HTMLCanvasObject`, how do you get it to return a `HTMLCanvasElement`?

(https://simon.html5.org/dump/html5-canvas-cheat-sheet.html)

Comment: On Chrome, `document.createElement('canvas')` does return an `HTMLCanvasElement`, not `HTMLCanvasObject`.

Comment: I called ctx2.drawImage(ctx1,0,0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not even sure how you would get a `HTMLCanvasObject`, but `document.getElementById()` returns a `HTMLCanvasElement` which you can use as an argument to `drawImage`.

```
   var canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas1");
   var canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");

   var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
   ctx2.drawImage(canvas1, 10, 10);
```

I'm new to Plunker, but I've cobbled together this little demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/OrZ31Ohnln6lDo181Qo0?p=preview